# More optimize way to find whether user likes the post or not in infinite post feed

Tags: firebase, react-native, optimization, infinite-scroll, virtualscroll

I'm working on a React Native social media project, focusing on the post feed screen. I'm wondering about the most **efficient way to determine whether a user has liked a post**. In scenarios where there are thousands of likes for a particular post, the naive approach of iterating through all the likes and matching the userId can be quite costly, especially when dealing with multiple posts simultaneously.
Any suggestions on optimizing performance would be greatly appreciated.

For optimization I am rendering 10 posts at a time and cached them and when user scroll down, next 10 records will be fetched, but I am wondering is there still a better approcah to tackle this problem.

I am using **Firebase** for storage now

Comment: A few things: app design questions are really tough to address here on SO due to the dialog that's required and use case. Asking about the *most efficient way* is also challenging as *efficient* could mean different things to different people. Lastly, *iterating through* is likely unnecessary. If the structure allows for it, you can simply try to read the node in question and if it exists, the user liked that post. Firebase is a suite of products from the Realtime Database, to Firestore to Storage.  Which Firebase product are you using?

Comment: I am using firestore database, and currently there is Post Record with liked attribute that contains list of userId, I am iterating through it and find whether userId exist in liked attribute, if there it means user liked the post

Comment: Again, if the structure is correct you could directly read the document to see if the users uid existed. For example within the node in question you could store a series of documents with a collection (or sub collection) with the uid being the document id and a child field storing a value of true. Your read would be at `/collection/document (the uid)/` and if that document exists then they liked the post. There are about 100 other ways to approach it but that's pretty straight forward without iterating